# Conjugate continuous?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $X$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

And $f : w \in \mathbb{R}^{X} \rightarrow f(w) \in \mathbb{R}^{X}$ such as $f(w)(x_{i}) = w^{*}(x_{i})$

Is $f$ continuous ? (We consider $\mathbb{R}^{X}$ as a normed vector space).

I wish you a good day, thank you.

Of course $w^{*} : y \in \mathbb{R^{n}} \rightarrow \sup_{x \in X} \{ \langle x,y \rangle - w(x) \}$

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean the [Fenchel conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) function, so could you clarify your notation a bit? What is $w^*(x_i)$?

Comment: Of course $w^{*} : y \in \mathbb{R^{n}} \rightarrow \sup_{x \in X} \{ \langle x,y \rangle - w(x) \}$

Comment: You need to specify which norm $\mathbb{R}^X$ is equipped with. What is more, you should restrict to convex functions, I guess.